# I have this error from My Lightning Message Channel in LWC. What can cause this?

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

I have this error from My Platform Events (via lightning/empApi) in LWC.

I get this when i use the "onError" method from 'lightning/empApi'.

What can cause this ?

[image: Error on Message Channel]

Any help will be appreciated .

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The channel is telling you that you need to do a new handshake. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_handling_errors.htm):

> 403 Unknown Client Error
>
> If a long-lived connection is lost due to unexpected network disruption, the CometD server times out the client and deletes the client state. The CometD client attempts to reconnect but the connection is rejected with the 403::Unknown client error because the client state doesn't exist anymore. The error response returned when the client attempts to reconnect after a timeout looks similar to the following message.

...

> When the client receives the 403::Unknown client error with the "reconnect":"handshake" advice field, the client must perform a new handshake. If the handshake is successful, the client must resubscribe to the channel in the handshake listener.

You're likely getting this error because of network connectivity issues. In order to fix it, try calling `subscribe()` again if you get this message in your error handler (or, generally speaking, whenever `error.advice.reconnect` equals `handshake`).